# PostgreSQL - Extract value out of an array with position

Tags: postgresql

I want to extract a value out of an array of numerical values with index position in PostgreSQL.

My array is like `{0.10,0.20,0.30}`, type is `numeric[]`, array position is an `integer` calculated with `array_position`. Syntax will be `SELECT myarray[array_position];`, but when I try (for example) :

```
SELECT'{0.10,0.20,0.30}'::numeric[][1];
```

It returned me the entire array.

How to extract a value out of an array with index position in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example `[1]` is the part of array definition: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION

> However, the current implementation ignores any supplied array size limits, i.e., the behavior is the same as for arrays of unspecified length.

Use parentheses to split the definition and reference:

```
SELECT ('{0.10,0.20,0.30}'::numeric[])[1];
```

Comment: I don't know I have to split definition and reference with parentheses but it's logic when you write it.